# Versioning ActiveRecord on Sinatra, not Rails?

Tags: activerecord, sinatra, versioning

I just had a quick look at the available solutions and the main two ones don't work for me:

- paper trail is not actively maintained since 3 months and is tied to Rails 3;
- vestal versions is not maintained since 2 years.

Can you suggest a solution? Should I implement mine? Problem is I have a tight deadline.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gone for my own fast implementation, model with polymorphic association and a text field where I marshal the associated object into.